# What is a "structured variable"?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable, terminology

My supervisor uses this notion. But I can't find any reference online. He gives an example, $x \in [0,1]^m $.

Comment: Why not just ask *him*?

Comment: @mkt  He explains this in an unclear way. I ask here because I am curious if this notion is used in statistics or is something that he created on his own.

Answer (score 1):

As said in a comment, only your supervisor can know why he uses that term, so ask him! But, I guess he has a computer science background, in which case he is probably using the meaning in [this dictionary](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199234004.001.0001/acref-9780199234004-e-5123), which is

> A variable in a programming language that is a composite object, being
>   made up of components that are either simple ...

But some papers seem to be using this term *structured variable* in a more statistical sense, like [STRUCTURED VARIABLE SELECTION AND ESTIMATION](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.0610.pdf),
[Bayesian hierarchical structured variable selection methods with application to MIP studies in breast cancer](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25705056),    [Structured variable selection with q-values](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3841382/).

[google scholar finds some more](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=gsb40&q=%22structured%20variable%22&lookup=0&hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

By $[0, 1]^m$ he probably means a *product* of unit intervals (i.e., a cube), so $x \in [0, 1]^m$ would mean that $x$ is $m$-dimensional and each element is between 0 and 1.